# Nested sum of binomial coefficient in closed form

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Let $\ell$ be an even positive integer.  Express $$\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^\ell (-1)^i\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{2k}{i}\binom{2n-2k}{\ell-i}$$in closed form.

Is anybody to give a insight, please?
[A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates] p.192
problem 8.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let  $\ell=2m$, then
>   $$S_{n,m}:=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{2m} (-1)^i\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{2k}{i}\binom{2n-2k}{2m-i}=\binom{2m}{m}\binom{2(n-m)}{n-m}.$$

Note that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m} (-1)^i\binom{2k}{i}\binom{2n-2k}{2m-i}=[x^{2m}](1-x)^{2k}(1+x)^{2n-2k},$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
S_{n,m}&=[x^{2m}]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2(1-x)^{2k}(1+x)^{2n-2k}\\
&=[x^{2m}]4^nx^n P_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\\
&=[x^{2m}]\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{2m}{m}\binom{2(n-m)}{n-m}x^{2m}
=\binom{2m}{m}\binom{2(n-m)}{n-m}
\end{align}$$
where $P_{n}$ is the $n$-th [Legendre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Explicit_representations).

Comment: Thank you!
You gave to me, new item, Legendre Polynomial.
It's so concise. Thank you, again.

Comment: But I can't grasp the last result, $ \binom{2m}{m}  \binom{2n-2m}{n-m} $.  \newline  Please help me out the induction from $ P_n  \left(  \frac{1}{2} (x+ 1/x) \right) $

Comment: You asked for an insight, not for a full solution (without effort)...

Comment: I'm sorry, but thank you